# Search for "bar" while using norm! in Vim

Tags: vim, replace

I have a text that looks like this:

```
foo x1
ddd
ggg
...
bar
```

I want to yank the word after foo, go to the line were bar is, replace bar with txt, and paste the yanked word.

I need to replace in this code the "j" with something that searches for "bar"

```
:/^foo/norm! wywj0rtlrxlrt"0p
```

Now I get this result:

```
foo x1
txtx1. 
ggg
...
bar
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could simply replace the motion `j` with `/bar`.

To tell `:normal` that you want to hit `Enter` and validate your search, you can insert a literal carriage return on the command-line by pressing `C-v` then `Enter`, and it would give this command:

```
:norm! wyw/bar^M0rtlrxlrt"0p
```

`^M` is the caret notation of a literal carriage return.

Or you could wrap the whole command inside a non-literal string (surrounded by double quotes), in which you can express a carriage return with the notation `\<cr>` or `\r`, and execute the contents of the string with `:execute`. It would give:

```
:exe "/^foo/norm! wyw/bar\r0rtlrxlrt\"0p"
```

Here, `\r` stands for the carriage return necessary to validate your search, and since the string must use double quotes, the double quote of the copy register (`"0`) must be escaped.